# В Termux не клонируется репозиторий с github

Tags: android, github, link, termux, git-clone

При попытке клонировать

```
~ $ git clone https://github.com/B41B4L/FakeRoot
```

Cloning into 'FakeRoot'...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found: needed by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libssh2.so in namespace (default)
~ $